# Confusion related to the convexity of a bunch of functions

Tags: functions, convex-optimization

I have this confusion related to the convexity of some functions. I was reading [this paper](https://kdd.org/exploration_files/V14-01-02-Ye.pdf). I have this graph consisting of nodes denoted by $x_i$. Some of these nodes are connected through edges. I am confused about the convexity of the following function

$F_1 = x^TLx$ where $x=[x_1,x_2,...x_N]$ N is the number of nodes and L is the Laplacian matrix

$F_2 = \sum_{i,j \epsilon E} |x_i-x_j|$ where E is the set of edges

$F_3 =  \sum_{i,j \epsilon E} max\{|x_i|,|x_j|\}$

$F_4 =  \sum_{i,j \epsilon E} ||x_i|-|x_j||$

It is said that except function $F_4$, all the other functions are convex. I want the intuition behind all this. Any help?

Comment: You have a typo: $| |x_{i}| - |x_{j}| |$ at place of $||x_{i}|, |x_{j}||$.

Comment: [Here's a Wayback version](https://web.archive.org/web/20221221222327/https://kdd.org/exploration_files/V14-01-02-Ye.pdf) of the linked paper in case the link ever rots again

Answer (score 0):

$F_1$: the graph Laplacian is positive semidefinite, hence the second derivative $F_1''$ is a positive semidefinite matrix, and $F_1$ is convex.

$F_2,F_3$: are sums of convex functions. The function $|\cdot|$ is convex (it is a norm),  $\max(\cdot,\cdot)$ is a convex function, too.

Comment: How come the fourth function is not convex? I plotted the function. It is certainly not convex. But I want to know about it from the properties of absolute values